# SQL Query with multiple CASE statements using the same field as THEN

Tags: sql-server, case

Any idea why my case statement for UOMC.ToUnitOfMeasure returns NULL? If I reverse and show the To field before the from field, to will work but from will not.

```
SELECT 
    ECORESPRODUCT.DISPLAYPRODUCTNUMBER, 
    ECORESPRODUCT.SEARCHNAME, 
    INVENTTABLE.ITEMID, 
    UOMC.NUMERATOR,
    UOMC.DENOMINATOR, 
    CASE
       WHEN UOMC.FROMUNITOFMEASURE = UOM.RECID
         THEN UOM.SYMBOL
         ELSE 'NULL'
    END AS 'FROM UNIT',
    CASE
       WHEN UOMC.TOUNITOFMEASURE = UOM.RECID
         THEN UOM.SYMBOL
       ELSE 'NULL'
    END AS 'TO UNIT'
FROM 
    ECORESPRODUCT
JOIN 
    INVENTTABLE ON INVENTTABLE.RECID = ECORESPRODUCT.RECID
JOIN 
    UNITOFMEASURECONVERSION AS UOMC ON UOMC.PRODUCT =  ECORESPRODUCT.RECID
JOIN 
    UNITOFMEASURE AS UOM ON UOM.RECID = UOMC.FROMUNITOFMEASURE
WHERE 
    INVENTTABLE.NAMEALIAS <> 'Discontinued' 
    AND INVENTTABLE.COSTGROUPID = 'FG'
```

Comment: Where do you check result? SSMS or your app?

Comment: Shouldn't you have NULL instead of the string literal 'NULL'?

Comment: Not sure, but I think that you need two joins to `UNITOFMEASURE`. First by `UOMC.FROMUNITOFMEASURE` (which you already have in join list) and second by `UOMC.TOUNITOFMEASURE`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two **references** (TO and FROM) so you have to **refer** your directory `UNITOFMEASURE` twice:

```
SELECT
  ...
  UOM_FROM.SYMBOL as 'FROM UNIT',
  UOM_TO.SYMBOL as 'TO UNIT'
FROM
...
INNER JOIN UNITOFMEASURECONVERSION AS UOMC ON UOMC.PRODUCT =  ECORESPRODUCT.RECID
INNER JOIN UNITOFMEASURE AS UOM_FROM ON UOM_FROM.RECID = UOMC.FROMUNITOFMEASURE
INNER JOIN UNITOFMEASURE AS UOM_TO ON UOM_TO.RECID = UOMC.TOUNITOFMEASURE
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan that resolved it, can't believe I missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being the correct syntax. Was missing the extra join needed to match the TO unit and the FROM.
    `SELECT 
    ECORESPRODUCT.DISPLAYPRODUCTNUMBER, 
    ECORESPRODUCT.SEARCHNAME, 
    INVENTTABLE.ITEMID, 
    UOMC.NUMERATOR,
    UOMC.DENOMINATOR,
    CASE WHEN UOMC.FROMUNITOFMEASURE = UOM_FROM.RECID
      THEN UOM_FROM.SYMBOL
      END AS 'FROM UNIT', 
    CASE WHEN UOMC.TOUNITOFMEASURE = UOM_TO.RECID
      THEN UOM_TO.SYMBOL
      END AS 'TO UNIT'
    FROM ECORESPRODUCT
    JOIN INVENTTABLE ON INVENTTABLE.RECID = ECORESPRODUCT.RECID
    INNER JOIN UNITOFMEASURECONVERSION AS UOMC ON UOMC.PRODUCT = ECORESPRODUCT.RECID
    INNER JOIN UNITOFMEASURE AS UOM_FROM ON UOM_FROM.RECID = UOMC.FROMUNITOFMEASURE
    INNER JOIN UNITOFMEASURE AS UOM_TO ON UOM_TO.RECID = UOMC.TOUNITOFMEASURE
    WHERE INVENTTABLE.NAMEALIAS <> 'Discontinued' AND INVENTTABLE.COSTGROUPID = 'FG'`